# Using a Symfony custom validation constraint by its service name

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.8

I have created the following custom validation constraint:

```
validator.constraint.user.email_unicity:
    class: AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\User\EmailUnicityValidator
    tags:
        - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: user_email_unicity_validator }
```

I added it to my field as follows:

```
AppBundle\Security\User\WebserviceUser:
    properties:
        email:
            - AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\User\EmailUnicity: ~
```

But I wanted avoid using the full path of my classe by using the constraint's alias but didn't find the right way. Something like that:

```
AppBundle\Security\User\WebserviceUser:
    properties:
        email:
            - user_email_unicity_validator: ~
```

or

```
AppBundle\Security\User\WebserviceUser:
    properties:
        email:
            - @user_email_unicity_validator: ~
```

In both cases I got the following exception:

> Attempted to load class "[alias name]" from namespace "\Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints".
>   Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Is there a way to do that?

Thank's all! :)

**[EDIT 2015/12/10]**

I tried with following alias, but not better (same exception message):

```
{ name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: User\EmailUnicityValidator }
```

**[EDIT 2015/12/11]**

Here my code details:

```
# AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\User\EmailUnicity.php
namespace AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\User;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

class EmailUnicity extends Constraint
{
    public $messageMatchesFound = '[...]';

    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return 'user_email_unicity_validator';
    }
}
```

.

```
# AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\User\EmailUnicityValidator.php
namespace AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\User;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class EmailUnicityValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($email, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        [...]
    }
}
```

Comment: Drop the @ and it should work.  Aliases are not service id's.

Comment: No more. Actually, that was the first thing I tried. 
Indeed, I got the following error : "Attempted to load class "user_email_unicity_validator" from namespace "\Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints". Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?". Same error by using this alias "User\EmailUnicityValidator".

Comment: The alias is the correct entry.  You have to follow certain conventions in your constraint class.  All I can suggest is to work your way through the examples in the docs (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html) and then try to rename to you class.  Sort of guessing that maybe your validatedBy method is not returning the correct value.  Msybe post the relevant portions of your classes.

Comment: I updated my post with more details. Many thanks for your help Cerad!